# Laravel Passport - Client authentication failed

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I've installed Laravel Passport.

First time I run the following URL: `http://127.0.0.1:9000/oauth/authorize?client_id=3&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8000/callback&response_type=code&scope&state=asd1231asd123123`

I get redirected to the Login route. I do the login and after the login is done when I try to open again the same URL `http://127.0.0.1:9000/oauth/authorize?client_id=3&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8000/callback&response_type=code&scope&state=asd1231asd123123`

It gives me the following error:

```
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client authentication failed","message":"Client authentication failed"}
```

Why is that?

Comment: I am not sure about Laravel Passport, but normally the same `state` value cannot be reused.